# ajax/jquery - including script into a dynamic web page (SPA)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I m setting up a single page application using AJAX and JAVASCRIPT(JQUERY) with [this tutorial](https://ilovecoding.org/lessons/ajax-create-a-single-page-app-with-jquery) :

1. firstly i get the link in the `<a>` tag with this code :

   ```
    $('a').on('click',function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pageRef = $(this).attr('href');
        callPage(pageRef);
     });
   ```
2. after that i get the page required in to include in index.html page by this code :

   ```
   function callPage(url)
   {
   $.ajax({
       url : url,
       type: "GET",
       dataType : "text",
       success : function(response)
       {
           console.log("the page was loaded",response);
           $('#content').html(response);
       },
       error : function(error)
       {
           console.log("the page wasn't loaded",error);
       },
       complete : function(xhr , status)
       {
           console.log("the requeste is complete");
       } 
   });
    }
   ```
3. and finally i have this test script in hello.js :

   ```
    $('#btn').on('click',function()
     {
          alert("hello world");
     });
   ```

   and this is all the pages concerned :

index.html :

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
          <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>

      <div id="main">
              <h1>TEST SINGLE PAGE APPLICATION WITH AJAX AND JQUERY</h1>
              <ul>
                   <li><a href="./about.html">about</a></li>
                   <li><a href="./contact.html">contact</a></li>
                   <li><a href="./hello.html">hello</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id="content"></div>
      </div>


      <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/hello.js"></script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

hello.html :

```
      <button id="btn">say hello world</button>
```

now all is working fine, but when I click on #btn the alert message don't appear, but when I include hello.js file in hello.html page its work, can someone tell me the reason why the first case doesn't work? because when jquery include the page (hello.html)  and include the script (hello.js) in the index.html, the hello.html, and hello.js gonna be in the same place, so why the button #btn don't work?
thank you in advance ...

Comment: Because the button doesn't exist yet when the click handler code tries to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Event delegation for your ajax content.

[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation
>   (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the
>   element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single
>   event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.

change hello.js code to this.

```
$(document).on("click", '#btn', function(event) { 
    alert("hello world");
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response, and also for the code.

Comment: If this answers help you.please accept it so it also help others with similar problem

Comment: Welcome @ekka :)

Comment: can you share the link for the documentation above.

Comment: It's Done ekka.   :)

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching click event to a button that doesnt yet exist for DOM, because your hello.html is not rendered yet. that is why it wont work.