# jquery / ajax - event propagation with append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m working on a single page application using AJAX and JAVASCRIPT(JQUERY), so I do the following step :

1. firstly I get the link in the  tag with ([see my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333105/ajax-jquery-including-script-into-a-dynamic-web-page-spa/50333216?noredirect=1#comment87685522_50333216)).
2. after that i get the page required to include in index.html page (also see my previous post).

like this the a link gonna inject the code of the page into the index page.

3. index.html :

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Document</title>
     </head>
     <body>

       <div id="main">
              <h1>TEST SINGLE PAGE APPLICATION WITH AJAX AND JQUERY</h1>
              <ul>
                   <li><a href="./about.html">about</a></li>
                   <li><a href="./contact.html">contact</a></li>
                   <li><a href="./hello.html">hello</a></li>
              </ul>
           <div id="content"></div>
           </div>


           <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
           <script src="./js/hello.js"></script>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```
4. and this is hello.html :

   ```
     <select id="typeUser">
           <option value="empty">choose type of user</option>
     </select>
     <button id="btn">say hello world</button>
   ```
5. and this the script of hello.html page (hello.js) :

   ```
     var typeUser = ["user" , "administrator"];
     $(document).on('click','#btn',function(e)
     {
          alert("hello world");
     });
     typeUser.forEach(e =>{
           $('select#userType').append('<option>'+e+'</option>');
     });
   ```

the problem is when the foreach loop starts the div#content was empty, and the select#userType don't exist yet, what I want is to load the array typeUser to the select#typeUser tag without including the script hello.js into hello.html page.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Small side note.  `$(this).attr('href');` could be just `this.href`.  `href` is a property on the dom Element.

Comment: You can use onload event  in hello.html that will trigger a method with the foreach loop

Comment: thank you @GilEpshtain but i have never used onload , can you set an example, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in the success callback after the code is loaded into DOM?

```
success : function(response) {
   console.log("the page was loaded",response);
   $('#content').html(response);
   let options = '';
   $.each(["user" , "administrator"], function(index, type) {
     options += `<option>${type}</option>`;
   });
   $('select#userType').html(options);
}
```

Although, isn't the point of a SPA to have all of your code in one place so you don't have to deal with these kind of issues?

Comment: thank you very much for your response, is the inclusion of hello.js into hello.html have any disadvantages.

Comment: That's a good question for the google. There's pros and cons to both styles and there plenty of debate about it. In my opinion, and experience, it's just easier to have everything in one place. It mitigates fragmentation, server response issues/missing resources, timing of asynchronous responses (possibly your issue). It simplifies debugging by not having to trace the source file(s) of the issue. For the user experience, mutating the DOM is faster than contacting the server, and then mutating the DOM. Although it all depends on the situation of your project.